# metodo firstOrCreate no funciona? registros duplicados laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

hace unos días consulté algo similar, en el cual se me creaban registros duplicados, gracias a uno de ustedes, lo solucioné, pero nuevamente tengo el mismo problema:

aquí mi código

```
   public function store()
    {
            $datos_super= DB::table('super')->select(['zona','codigo'])->first();
            //dump($datos_super);
            $flujo = DB::table('flujos')->select('destino','producto')->where('zona',$datos_super->zona)->get();
            //dump($flujo);
            if(strlen($datos_super->codigo)==9){
                $fundo = (int) substr($datos_super->codigo,0,3);
            }else{
                $fundo = (int) substr($datos_super->codigo,0,4);
            } 
            foreach ($flujo as $f) {
                $datos_transpor = DB::table('d_transporte')->where('cod_fundo',$fundo)->where('destino',$f->destino)->first();
               // dump($datos_transpor);
                $especie = DB::table('productos')->where('producto',$f->producto)->value('especie');
                if($especie == 1){
                    $a = 0.177548*$datos_transpor->dist_no_pavimento;
                    $b = 0.0746*$datos_transpor->dist_pavimento;
                    $c = 0.0333*$datos_transpor->peaje;
                    $costo = $a + $b + 1.1191 + 0.399 + $c;   
                 } 
                 Transpor::firstOrCreate([
                    'zona' => $datos_super->zona,
                    'destino' => $f->destino,
                    'producto' => $f->producto,
                    'costo' => $costo
                ]);  
           }    

    }
```

para colocarlos mas en contexto debo llenar una tabla llamada `traspor` con datos de otras para finalmente que se vea así: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver lo marcado se ha repetido, si hago un dump de `$flujo` me muestra lo sgte:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve hay solo 2 elementos en el array, entonces no entiendo porque se crean 4 registros :( , la vez pasada me pasaba lo mismo, pero al hacer el `firstOrCreate` se solucionó pero ahora no sé que pasa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si consultamos en la propia [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods), veremos que el método `firstOrCreate()` ocupa 2 parámetros en forma de vector.

- El primero va a ser aquel por el cual realices la búsqueda y en caso de encontrar el registro te retorne dicha colección
- El segundo va a ser aquel vector con los valores que vas a ingresar en caso de que no haya encontrado coincidencia con algún registro y por lo tanto no te haya devuelto alguna colección

Entonces tu consulta podría quedar del modo siguiente:

```
Transpor::firstOrCreate(
                            [
                                'columna' => valor a ocupar para filtrar
                            ],
                            [
                                'zona' => $datos_super->zona,
                                'destino' => $f->destino,
                                'producto' => $f->producto,
                                'costo' => $costo
                            ]
                        );
```

Entonces donde yo coloqué **valor a ocupar para filtrar** tu debes establecer tal vez por medio de un `$request` el valor dinámico que usarás para filtrar y donde coloqué columna elige una de tu tabla para realizar la búsqueda.

Entonces estableciendo el primer vector ya no debería permitirte ingresar valores duplicados.

Comment: gracias, funciona ok!